# Issue with calling webmethod after deploying project

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, hosting, web-deployment

This is my set up.

I have a form where a user can leave their email to get notifications.

```
    <form id="contactForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter email" />
<span class="input-group-btn"><button id="sendEmail" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Get notified!</button></span>
        </div>
        <div id="sendmessage"></div>
    </form>
```

On submitting the form the following Ajax call is made:

```
$(function () {
            $("[id*=sendEmail]").click(function () {
                var obj = {};
                obj.from = $.trim($("[id*=inputEmail]").val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/SendParameters",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (r) {
                        alert(r.d);
                    }

                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

which in turns calls the following webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string SendParameters(string from)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(from))
            {
                return string.Format("Please complete the form.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Port = 80;


                    client.Host = "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net";

                    client.EnableSsl = false;
                    client.Timeout = 10000;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my@email.com", "myPassword");
                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, "my@email.com", "Notify website launch", "Please let me know when it's ready!");
                    mm.BodyEncoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                    mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                    client.Send(mm);
                    return string.Format("Thank you!<br/>I'll be in touch soon.");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    return string.Format("Oops, your message could not be sent.<br/>Please retry.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Locally this works like a clockwork but after deploying my project to my GoDaddy shared server, the worst error is thrown:

> POST http://simoneduca.com/Default.aspx/SendParameters 500 (Internal Server Error)

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

I have been bashing my head for 3 hours now so any word of advice would be very welcome.

(I love that SO suggested `bash` as a tag for this question, LOL)

Comment: does GO Daddy support .net..have you contacted their support also have you checked to make sure that the .dll's are Copyied over properly meaning in your project.. did you set the .dll's `CopyToLocal = true` you need to make sure that you have all the .dll's and assemblies referenced / copied over properly..

Comment: @MethodMan that did the trick. Obvious in hindsight, but thanks a lot! If you care to move your comment into an answer I'll accept it (might be helpful to somebody else). Btw I also needed to [change my trust level to full](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8999/do-your-hosting-accounts-support-mvc4-and-mcv5-applications).